# Azure Devops Wishlist backlog (StakeHolder create Work Item, but don't edit)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, edit, rules, backlog

We are using Azure Devops with our team, we want to have a space were other colleagues out of our team can add ideas about future project.

We created a specific Backlog "Wishlist" and give to some users a StakeHolder account. We added them to the members of this backlog.

We want them to be able to create ticket, but not to edit them (no delete, no chamgement of state ...)
Our team that have admin rights will be able to operate those work items (accepted, rejected, Active and Close)

I look for a solution to restrict those user from editing but was not able to found a successful way to do it.

-In Rules, We couldn't specify those specific rule about work Item edition

-In Project Settings / Permissions / Wishlist
we don't have any permision linked to the Work Items

-In Project Settings / Project Configuration / Areas / Wishlist / Security 
We can set for specific users "Edit Work Items in this node" to Deny, but they will not be able to create Work items

If someone have an idea about how to deal with this request, it will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's not able to do this right now.

A user needs to have the **Edit work items in this node** permission for some Area and Iteration path to create a work item.

There is no sperate permission for either creating or editing work item. This is by designed.